# c# Recursive Method Parameter

Tags: c#, recursion, methods, syntax, parameters

This is not important. I just wondered. Thank you in advance for your help.

```
void AddAccount(string name, string surname, DateTime age, string phone, string username, string pwd)
{
     // Codes...
     // I want to call this method again.
     // This a example.


     if(Msg("Registration is available. Add it again."))
        AddAccount(name, surname, age, phone, username, pwd);
}
```

Is there a method that automatically takes parameters instead?

I know I can do it differently. But I just wondered about the existence of such a syntax.

Comment: You should ask your question in text, not in code. Then provide a code sample for context or example.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. What are you asking exactly?

Comment: You are already showing an example of recursion, however it will run forever (well, until you get a `StackOverflowException`). Normally if you want a recursive call, you will have some condition that you check that will, at some point, stop the recursion. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I just want to recall this method in a code using just the same parameters. This will be processed with confirmation of a message box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is a shortcut to avoid specifying the parameters again:

```
void AddAccount(string name, string surname, DateTime age, string phone, string username, string pwd)
{
     // Codes...
     // I want to call this method again.

     // Is there a method that automatically takes parameters instead?
     AddAccount(params);
}
```

No such syntax exists in C#.  An alternative would be to create a parameters type:

```
private struct Person 
{
    public string Name;
    public string Surname;
    public DateTime Age;
    public string Phone;
    public string Username;
    public string Password;
}
```

Then you could have a private overload that takes the param class:

```
void AddAccount(string name, string surname, DateTime age, string phone, string username, string pwd)
{
     Person person = new Person
     {
        Name = name,
        Surname = surname,
        Age = age,
        Phone = phone,
        Username = username,
        Password = password
     }
     AddAccount(person);
}

private void AddAccount(Person person)
{
     // Codes...

     // I want to call this method again.
     AddAccount(person);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. It's a longer but a solution to rewriting these parameters. I wanted to learn to reduce code complexity. Thank you for learning that there is no such word.

Comment: One other benefit is it allows for better type safety.  You could easily switch the `name` and `surname` parameters in the second call and the compiler wouldn't complain, but you'd obviously have problems at runtime.

Comment: I'll use it in some places. Thank you. @D Stanley